# Passing arrays with ajax to custom endpoints

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am using ajax to send data to a custom rest endpoint. I am doing this because i'm creating a filter function on my WP site.

Now I am stuck trying to get the tax_query to work with my array of terms collected with JS on the front end. No matter what I do I cant seem to get this to work, and I am strongly suspecting this is only a minor error that I keep overlooking...

Just to clarify, the ajax sends the request successfully but the query returns all posts no matter what.

**Here is the checkboxes used on the front end:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php
if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'utst', 'hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
        echo '<div class="form-check">';
        echo '<label class="form-check-label" for="'.$term->slug.'"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="'.$term->slug.'" name="utstyrAr[]" value="'.$term->term_id.'"> '.$term->name.'</label>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
        echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
</div>
```

**The JS (ajax function):**

```
filterOppdrag(fiOppdrag) {

    var utst = [];

    var utstyrArray = document.getElementsByName("utstyrAr[]");

    for (var i = 0; i < utstyrArray.length; i++) {
      if(utstyrArray[i].type =='checkbox' && utstyrArray[i].checked == true) utst.push(utstyrArray[i].value);
    }
    console.log(utst);

    $.ajax({
      url: the.root + '/wp-json/myfilter/v1/filter',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
             'checkUtst'    : utst,
           },
      success: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      } 
    });
    }
```

**And the wp_query (php):**

```
function myFilter ($data) {

        $checkUtst          = sanitize_text_field($data['checkUtst']);

        //Main $args
          $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'ml_opp', // Query only "ml_opp" custom posts
            'post_status'   => 'publish', // Query only posts with publish status
            'orderby'       => 'date', // Sort posts by date
            'order'         => 'ASC' // ASC or DESC
          );

          // for taxonomies / utstyr
          if( isset( $utstyr ) )
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
              array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'ml_utst',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => $checkUtst
              )
            );

          $query = new WP_Query( $args );

          if( $query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
              echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
          else :
            echo 'No posts found';
          endif;
          die();
    }
```

This returns all the posts regardless of terms no matter what I pass through. I get no error messages and yes I have tested so that there is value in the array when I send it to the query. But what happens to it on the road there, I dont know. That's why i figure that Its probably just a rookie mistake I am making here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the wrapping array and not using a key?

```
            $args = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'ml_utst',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => $checkUtst
            );
```

Comment: Yes, same negative result. I am wondering if it could be a quote issue? When I echo the variable in the query and look at the response in the console I see this `["7","26","9"]`

Comment: It looks like sanitize_text_field only accepts strings, but in your AJAX you are passing checkUtst as an array. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/

Comment: Yes, I just read actually. So I tried without sanitizing and get the exact same result as mentioned above in the comment.